# How do I upgrade my Matter Manipulator?

Tags: starbound

I've been playing Sarbound version 1.0 up until the first relic quest, I wan't to upgrade my MM (Matter Manipulator) but I must have skipped the tutorial which people say is how you unlock it. After looking through a couple of similar people's issues I've seen a bunch of people saying "activate the teleporter" or take the the flashlight out of the locker but nothing seems to work. Any one know how to fix this issue. (I also looked at S.A.I.L. and their's only the Dreadwing quests and Revisit the Erchius Mining Facility)

Comment: Your question is very confusing... are you asking how to start the tutorial quest, or how to upgrade your matter manipulator? Those are two very different answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there is a tutorial on how to upgrade your matter manipulator. Information you find online is likely outdated, as the 1.0 release was only a couple of days ago.

To upgrade your matter manipulator, click on the "MM upgrade" button on the right:

[image: Matter manipulator upgrade button]

In the window that pops up, select one of the available upgrades, and then press the <kbd>UPGRADE</kbd> button:

[image: Matter manipulator upgrade window]

You'll need a certain number of [Manipulator Modules](http://starbounder.org/Manipulator_Module) to make an upgrade, which can be found in chests and reward bags.

Comment: Related note: I was playing for the first time in ages and had added the Frackin' Universe mod and the Quickbar mod.  This is buried in the Quickbar now, so if you can't find it and are using that mod, that's where it's hiding.  This answer helped me get there!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question that's being asked is how to unlock upgrades to the matter manipulator.  I'm assuming his screen is looking a lot like this, where there are enough manipulators, but no way to use them - they're still locked.

You have to select and upgrade the first tier.  That's the one with an icon in it.  Once that one is upgraded, then the next one will unlock.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to upgrade the matter manipulator you need to press on something that isn't greyed out- you can see the color on the water droplet, so if you click on it the upgrade button becomes yellow and you can update it. Having an expansion shot thats not locked doesn't mean that its an update you have.